# Help to understand a limit $\varepsilon\rightarrow 0$ computation on a fluid mechanic paper

Tags: real-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, applied-mathematics, fluid-dynamics

In [Córdoba and Gancedo - Contour dynamics of incompressible 3-D fluids in a porous medium with different densities](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/225499707_Contour_Dynamics_of_Incompressible_3-D_Fluids_in_a_Porous_Medium_with_Different_Densities) (page 4) I read that if
$$ v (x_1,x_2,x_3,t)=-\frac{\rho_2-\rho_1}{4\pi} \operatorname{PV}\int_{\mathbb{R}^2} \frac{(y_1,y_2,\nabla f(x-y,t)\cdot y)}{[\lvert y\rvert^2 + (x_3 - f(x-y,t)^2)]^{3/2}}\ dy$$ 
and for $\varepsilon $ positive and $x=(x_1,x_2)$, we define
$$ v^1(x_1,x_2,f(x,t),t) =\lim_{\varepsilon \rightarrow 0}  v\bigl(x_1-\varepsilon \partial_{x_1} f(x,t) , x_2 - \varepsilon \partial_{x_2} f (x,t), f(x,t) + \varepsilon , t\bigr),$$
then they say
\begin{align*}
v^1(x_1,x_2,f(x,t),t) ={} & v(x_1,x_2,f(x,t),t) \\
& {}+ \frac{\rho_2-\rho_1}{2}\frac{\partial_{x_1} f(x,t)(1,0,\partial_{x_1}f(x,t))}{1+(\partial_{x_1}f(x,t))^2 +(\partial_{x_2}f(x,t))^2 } \\
& {}+  \frac{\rho_2-\rho_1}{2}\frac{\partial_{x_2} f(x,t)(0,1,\partial_{x_2}f(x,t))}{1+(\partial_{x_1}f(x,t))^2 +(\partial_{x_2}f(x,t))^2 }.
\end{align*}

**I don't understand how they get that expression for $v^1$**. Please, any help or idea is welcome.

Comment: yeah, you are right.

Comment: I have made an edit. Thank you.

Comment: You might try a more descriptive title.  Your title suggests (before one clicks on it) that someone is looking for help with their calculus homework.

Comment: I second @AnthonyQuas's suggestion.

Comment: I've also edited it. Than for your suggestion.